# What is the Proper way to Change the Data Type of an Inherited Member Variable in Java?

Tags: java

Edit: Quick background: Foo is an abstract class whose sole purpose is to reduce redundancy in member variable declarations. It has no methods (aside from mutators and accessors) or explicit constructors.

I'm trying to "override" the data type of a member variable inherited from a parent. This doesn't appear legal to me.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import java.util.Date;

public abstract class Foo {
    private Date dt;
    public Date getDt() {
        return dt;
    }
}
public class Bar extends Foo {

}
public class Baz extends Foo {
    private DateTime dt;        //this is legal
    //causes: The return type is incompatable with Foo.getDt()
    public DateTime getDt() {   
        return dt;
    }
}
```

I noted that I am allowed to declare a variable of a different type with the same name in the inherited class, but I can't declare a accessor method that returns a different return type in the inherited class than in the parent class.

Am I supposed to forget about the contract and do it like so?

```
public abstract class Foo {
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    private Date dt;
    public Date getDt() {
        return dt;
    }
}

public class Baz extends Foo {
    private DateTime dt;
    public DateTime getDt() {
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Or is it best to make the parent's member variable's data type of `Object` and putting an accessor and mutator in the parent, and not making any corresponding member variables in the children?

```
public abstract class Foo {
    private Object dt;
    public Object getDt() {
        return dt;
    }
    public void setDt(Object dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }
}
public class Bar extends Foo {
}
public class Baz extends Foo {
}
```

Off that same line of thought, is this better than the above?

```
public class Baz extends Foo {
    public DateTime getDt() {
        return (DateTime) super.getDt();
    }
}
```

What is the best/most proper way to go about this?

Comment: It would be "legal", to provide a more specific return type in a subclass (e.g. returning a `Float` from a method, where the superclass returns `Number`). However, `DateTime` seems to be from Joda, so that does not apply in your case. Wouldn't it be possible to simply change everything to `DateTime` (`DateTime` provides a "conversion" constructor for converting a `Date`)?

Comment: @qqilihq No, I have a base model that extends to a model used in a MapReduce code, and that extends to another model used in a Pig UDF script. Pig UDF's only use the Joda DateTime.

Comment: Well, if there is no common denominator, it makes no sense to me to define it in a superclass/interface. What would be the advantage of having some "generic" Object field? It leads to ugly casts. Still, I don't get, why you need to provide the `Date` type, when you say everything in your project uses `DateTime`.

Comment: @qqilihq Foo isn't used at all (It is actually abstract; I'll edit above, sorry). It simply contains the member variables and corresponding mutator/accessor methods that will always be common to Bar and Baz, so that when a new attribute is required, I would only add it in one spot. I meant to say that MapReduce uses the Date object whereas Pig uses the Joda DateTime.

Comment: I think @erickson nailed it pretty well: The essential question should be: "what return type does that caller expect"? That's currently not clear, so giving any further advice is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have callers that invoke `getDt()` on a reference type of `Foo`?

If not, then `getDt()` should not be a member of `Foo`; it should be in subclasses or not exist at all.

If you do, then what return type does that caller expect? That is the type you should use.

APIs are written to support applications. Applications aren't written to consume APIs. What does your application require of `Foo`?

Comment: Foo isn't used at all (It is actually abstract; I'll edit above, sorry). It simply contains the member variables and corresponding mutator/accessor methods that will always be common to Bar and Baz, so that when a new attribute is required, I would only add it in one spot. Incidentally, Bar is used in MapReduce (Hadoop), Baz is used in Pig UDF.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen If `Foo` is never used as a reference type, consider eliminating it. Inheritance supports polymorphism; if you aren't treating `Bar` and `Baz` polymorphically as `Foo` instances, then why do they inherit? If they coincidentally have a lot of the same members and you want to avoid typing, consider factoring out the common stuff and share it through *composition.*

Comment: I don't mean to put too fine a point on it, but (ab)using inheritance to save key strokes leads to problems like this. Sometimes more typing is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Since your class Foo has declared the return type of `getDt()` to be `Date`, any overridden instances of that method must return Date or a subclass of `Date`.  Out of the solutions you have suggested, #2 makes more sense since you are returning two different sub-classes of `Object`, but I think this design choice is less than ideal.  Let me explain.

In order to handle such a design choice, any method that calls `getDt()` on Foo or any of its subclasses must do something like the following to determine how to interrogate the results:

```
Object date = Baz.getDt();
if (date instanceof Date) {
    ...
} else if (date instanceof DateTime) { 
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

In general, the combination of if/elseif blocks and `instanceof` is a bad idea.

A better idea would be to establish a generic object called, say, `FooDate`.  In your `Foo` class, you can define your `getDt()` method to return a `FooDate` object:

```
public class Foo {

    FooDate fooDate = null;

    public FooDate getDt() {
        return fooDate;
    }
}
```

Then each of the subclasses can take different constructors:

```
Bar(Date date) {
    //set fooDate
}

Baz(DateTime dateTime) {
    //set fooDate
}
```

The `FooDate` type would store the data you care about from each of the potential date-related types you have a subclass for, and you do the type interrogation in the constructor and return a consistent type that can be used without the need of a if/elseif block with `instanceof` checks.

EDIT: with the revelation that Foo is abstract, defer to erickson's answer.  His is more applicable in this case.